# React: How to inherit PropTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom, react-proptypes

I have a wrapper component for React Router Dom and Material UI:

```js
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import React from 'react';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const forwardedLink = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <RouterLink innerRef={ref} {...props} />
));

function Link(props) {
  return (
    <Button component={forwardedLink} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  );
}

Link.propTypes = // ?

export default Link;
```

How can I give `Link` the Prop-Types from `Button`?

Comment: `Link.propTypes = Button.propTypes;` ?

Comment: @zerkms This, unfortunately, doesn't work.

Comment: What "does not work" exactly mean?

Comment: It means that the component didn't get the `propTypes` 

Comment: Check this post out, If you are using propTypes mainly for intellisense it might help you, I just stumbled upon it , aspecially the section "The Trick" and the explanation "By adding @augments {Component<Props, State>} to your component's JSDoc, you'll add full PropTypes suggestions to your Class components :"

https://dev.to/maxbvrn/react-props-auto-complete-in-vs-code-2ana
 - and if it doesn't solve the issue it might point you in a direction =)

Answer (score 2):

> OOPS.. sorry, I didn't see at first you are trying to get the
>   propTypes from node-module.  anyhow.. if anyone needs this for
>   inheriting propTypes in own components I leave the answer*

**This works for me (using my own components)**
Export the props as a constant and assign it to the component.propTypes in the inherited and in the inheriting objects.

> Note, first I made a mistake that I didn't see. I had forgot to use shape on all the inner objects, like this:

```
export const configurationPropTypes = {  
  id: PropTypes.string,
  // note: PropTypes.shape not wrapping the 'os' object
  os: {
      version: PropTypes.string,
      locale: PropTypes.string
  }
};
```

> Above is wrong, below is correct. =)

```
//component being inherited 'ConfigurationListItem.js'
export const configurationPropTypes = {  
  id: PropTypes.string,
  os: PropTypes.shape({
      version: PropTypes.string,
      locale: PropTypes.string
  })
};

ConfigurationListItem.propTypes = configurationPropTypes;
```

```
//in 'QueueListItem.js', the component using ConfigurationListItem and inheriting it's propTypes

import ConfigurationListItem , {configurationPropTypes}from './ConfigurationListItem';
//...
QueueListItem.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  configurations: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape(configurationPropTypes))
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. And yes you're right, I'd like to know how to inherit from native tags. This answer will still probably be helpful for people looking to inherit custom Prop-Types 

Answer (score 2):

See [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66557201), the below should work.

```
/**
 * @type React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<React.FunctionComponent, ButtonPropTypes>
 */
const Button = forwardRef(({ text, icon }, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref}>{text}{icon}</button>
))

const ButtonPropTypes = {
  text: string.isRequired,
  icon: string.isRequired,
}

Button.propTypes = ButtonPropTypes
```