# How do i annotate React.forwardRef with jsdoc comments so that intellisense can show up for the underlying component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a React component written as a function this way:

```
function Button({ text, icon }) {
  return ...
}

Button.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

when using this component, I get the autocompletion / intellisense in vscode

If i wrap this component in React.forwardRef,
`export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Button btnRef={ref} {...props} />)`

then I get the intellisense for the `forwardRef` function, which does not help my usage, because now there is no way for me to get the props autocompleted / show up in intellisense.

I have tried annotating the `React.forwardRef` with jsdoc `extends` / `augments` but to no success, in that case even the default intellisense for `forwardRef` usage stops showing up. (I believe this is because vscode gives more preference to available types than jsdoc comments). Is there a way for me to get the intellisense for the wrapped component working similar to the unwrapped component? This would be inline with the understanding that I have for using the wrapped component in a similar way as the unwrapped component.

Comment: I know how to do this in typescript but I don't know what it looks like with just JSDoc.  It seems like you would want to include `btnRef` as a prop on `Button` though.

Comment: Yup, btnRef would be a prop to button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends how pedantic you want to be about the types. Generally, the use of these components is pretty much the same as other functional components, so the simplest way is to just declare the type of the result to be a functional component. The trick for the props is to first create a variable for the prop types and refer to that for the generic type (or at least, I haven't found a way to make it work without that interstitial value):

```
/**
 * @type React.FC<ButtonPropTypes>
 */
const Button = forwardRef(({ text, icon }, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref}>{text}{icon}</button>
))

const ButtonPropTypes = {
  text: string.isRequired,
  icon: string.isRequired,
  // `ref` isn't a "real" prop, so `prop-types` will not not actually validate
  // this one, but this adds it to the intellisense list if desired. Feel
  // free to just omit it.
  ref: oneOf(shape({ current: any }), func),
}

Button.propTypes = ButtonPropTypes
```

If you want to be more accurate, the return type of the `forwardRef` is actually:

```
/**
 * @type React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonPropTypes>
 */
const Button = forwardRef(({ text, icon }, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref}>{text}{icon}</button>
))

const ButtonPropTypes = {
  text: string.isRequired,
  icon: string.isRequired,
}

Button.propTypes = ButtonPropTypes
```

However, the IntelliSense doesn't seem to recognize the `ref` prop (works fine, just isn't in the list).

The definition for the type is here:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3423b4fc3e3da09f8acc386bc2fee6fb8f5e0880/types/react/index.d.ts#L559
The first parameter is the expected type for value that will be assigned to the ref. However, since you're not actually statically typing the `ref` that you would pass in anyway, you might just choose to omit that one with a `?`:

```
/**
 * @type React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<?, ButtonPropTypes>
 */
```

I *think* what you mean about the last part is that you wouldn't have both the unwrapped and the wrapped version. That's the typical pattern, as there is no real use for keeping both. However, as an aside, you can directly refer to the `propTypes` value of any other component for use as a generic type such as:

```
/**
 * @type React.FC<UnWrappedButton.propTypes>
 */
```

Comment: This seems to work at least for my particular use case. Thanks a ton! Now i just have to understand why @type annotation works but not augments / extends, which I use for general unwrapped components

Comment: Thank you, Erich! I used it like this: `@type React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<React.FunctionComponent, ButtonPropTypes>` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You probably don't want `React.FunctionComponent` as the first generic parameter. That param is for whatever will be stored IN the supplied `ref`, which will always be some sort of DOM element. So e.g. in the example above, the `ref` contains the actual HTML DOM element for a `button`. That first parameter is largely ignored by intellisense, which is why I suggested you could just use `?` for it, but for accuracy in the docs, it would be the encapsulated native element type.