# React.forwarRef breaks vscode's autocomplete for propTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, react-proptypes

Here is my approach.

If there is no `forwardRef`:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const Test = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.text}</div>;
};

Test.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  src: PropTypes.string
};
Test.displayName = "Test";

// use Test in useText
function useText() {
  return <Test />;
}
```

I can get the autocomplete from vscode like this:
[image]

BUT, when there is `forwardRef`:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const Test = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <div>{props.text}</div>;
});

Test.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  src: PropTypes.string
};
Test.displayName = "Test";

function useText() {
  return <Test />;
}
```

Nothing I can get from vscode autocomplete:
[image]

So I wonder is there a way to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553490/how-do-i-annotate-react-forwardref-with-jsdoc-comments-so-that-intellisense-can we need to declare it manually.

Comment: Try the below solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553490/how-do-i-annotate-react-forwardref-with-jsdoc-comments-so-that-intellisense-can